# CocoaLumberjack - how to access the log file on the device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, logging

I am using [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) for my logging as it seems a very versatile logging framework.

In my application, I need to log to a file, and have the contents of that file displayed in the app itself: this is for diagnostics purposes for the user of the app (mainly so they can see how much the app is accessing their network, which I log to file).

There is the `DDFileLogger` and `DDLogFileManager` classes. I can see how I can use the `DDLogFileManager` class to access a file once it's wrapped, but what I want to do is display the contents of the file in a `UITextView`  - so that it shows the current contents.. not just when it's wrapped.

Either way, I can't see how to access the log file within the app itself - can anyone shed some light on how to do this please?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11544657/620577

And these characters are just to reach the 30 minimum.